# How to change fontawsome icon onclick in a password field with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I want to make a script when the user click on the eye icon, the html code change to eye-slash icon and the password type change to text from password,and if the eye-slash icon is active then it change back to eye icon and the type will be password again.

Firstly I tried with two icon,and If i click on it one will disappears and one will appears,but now I see this is was a really bad idea,because this has some bugs.

So I want to toggle the html code with jquery.
And I tried to make if the input field is empty then the eye icon disappear,and if it has some text,then its appear.

But now I'm very confused,and I tired,so I would appreciate if someone can help me in this.

Or just sending me a sample about this.

```js
function hiddenscript() {
            var eye = document.getElementById("eye");
            eye.style.display = "block";        
}

function Showfunction() {
      var eye = document.getElementById("eye");
      var eye2 = document.getElementById("eye2");   
      var pass = document.getElementById("pass");
      var value = document.getElementById('pass').value;
  
         if(value.length > 0){
      eye.style.display = "block";    
    }
     if(value.length == 0)
       {
         eye.style.display = "none";
       }
         if (pass.type === "password") {
            pass.type = "text";
            eye.style.display = "none";
            eye2.style.display = "block";
            }
        else {
            pass.type = "password";
            eye2.style.display = "none";
            eye.style.display = "block";
            
            
    
            }       
}
```

```css
.passwordContainer {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 45px 0;
    width:355px;
    height:60px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
input {
    position:relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
    
  }
.fas {
  display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:-45px;
    position: relative;
    color: #555;
    font-size:23px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
}
#eye {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css" media="all">


<div class="passwordContainer">
<div class="fieldcontainer">  
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" class="input" maxlength="22" id="pass" oninput="hiddenscript()" required="">
  <div class="Eyeicon">
            <div class="eyeicon"><i class="fas fa-eye" id="eye" onclick="Showfunction()"></i></div>
     <!-- <i class="fas fa-eye-slash" id="eye2" onclick="Showfunction()"></i> -->
                        
</div> 
</div>

</div>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Element.classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) (please, avoid inline event handler):

```js
function hiddenscript() {
    var eye = document.getElementById("eye");
    if (document.getElementById("pass").value.trim().length == 0) {
        eye.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        eye.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function Showfunction() {
    var eye = document.getElementById("eye");
    var eye2 = document.getElementById("eye2");
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass");
    var value = document.getElementById('pass').value;

    if (value.length > 0) {
        eye.style.display = "block";
    }
    if (pass.type === "password") {
        pass.type = "text";
        eye.classList.toggle('fa-eye');
        eye.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
    } else {
        pass.type = "password";
        eye.classList.toggle('fa-eye');
        eye.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
    }
}
```

```css
.passwordContainer {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 45px 0;
    width: 355px;
    height: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

input {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;

}

.fas {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: -45px;
    position: relative;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 23px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
}

#eye {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css" media="all">


<div class="passwordContainer">
    <div class="fieldcontainer">
        <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" class="input" maxlength="22" id="pass"
               oninput="hiddenscript()" required="">
        <div class="Eyeicon">
            <div class="eyeicon"><i class="fas fa-eye" id="eye" onclick="Showfunction()"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And how can I make in jQuery,if the input field is empty the icon disappear,and if i type something it will appear again?